# Silverlight 4 and SAMI Subtitles

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, subtitle

I noticed a brief bit of info on the web that Silverlight 4 supports subtitles in .smi (SAMI) format. Is this true and does anyone have some more information?

David

Answer (score 1):

I have seen little evidence that Silverlight 4 supports SAMI files in any meaningful way.

This is the only reference I've seen which strongly indicates SAMI is supported, and it is buried in the comments of a blog post:

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/03/15/get-started-with-silverlight-for-windows-phone.aspx

Aside from this reference, all I can find are methods for implementing your own captioning, primarily for older versions of Silverlight. This reference seems to indicate that the media element in WPF also doesn't support SAMI, which to me makes it seem likely Silverlight doesn't, either.

[displaying subtitles for a video in a WPF MediaElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202810/displaying-subtitles-for-a-video-in-a-wpf-mediaelement)

There are a couple unanswered queries about this on Silverlight.net as well. It seems quite unlikely there's any support, since there seems to be no information on it.